# Silent install of application with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm working to automate the install of some of our software and was able to do so using a batch file, but was having issues with getting the silent install working in PowerShell.

The batch file which is working properly to install the application is:

```
@echo off
start /wait Setup.exe -s -l=EN
echo %errorlevel%
```

I've tried the following code in PowerShell, but the GUI installer will appear when I attempt to run it.

```
cmd.exe /c "Start /wait c:\temp\application\setup.exe -s -l=EN"
```

I don't receive any error messages when running the PowerShell script, it just doesn't install the application silently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
&{ "c:\temp\application\setup.exe" -s -l=EN }
```

This should call an external Commandline command from Powershell.

The braces are not always strictly necessary either if you are just running the command and not doing anything with the output the following would likely work

```
& c:\temp\application\setup.exe -s -l=EN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It doesn't seem like either one of those work. The first one give a syntax error for `-s -l=EN` and the second one will run but will have the GUI installer

Comment: What happens when you drop the quotes from the one with the braces?  ie `&{ c:\temp\application\setup.exe -s -l=EN }`

Comment: Nothing occurs when this method is attempted. When I run it, the script will not error out, nor does it show the GUI, it just has no response. The application isn't installing in the background either.

Comment: Sometimes instantiating them gets a little kludgy especially on older versions of Powershell..  You might consider just creating a CMD script in `c:\temp\application\` say `c:\temp\application\setup.cmd` and put the entirety of the contents of that file as `@( CALL "%~dpn0.exe" -s -l=EN )` which should do the needful if you double-click to run (or there is a problem with the syntax as a whole..) If that work stand alone, then you can call it from powershell liek this:  `& c:\temp\application\setup.cmd` or `&{ "c:\temp\application\setup.cmd" }`